# Inequality using position of roots

Tags: calculus

Suppose a is an integer.Consider the function defined on reals: $f(x) = 2x^4+3x^3-3x^2-6x+a =0.$ 
There is one root y  of $f(x)$ in $(1,2) $. Prove that
there exists a constant A > 0,such that for any postive 
integer p, q; where $ 1< p/q < y $ or  $ y<p/q < 2$,
it must hold that | $ p/q -y$| > $ \frac{1}{Aq^4}$

I tried with f(1)•f(2) < 0
by which i got a to lie between (-32,4).
after which i dont know how to proceed.

Comment: What has been erased at the top of the image?  This makes me immediately suspicious that this is a [homework exercise](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question), which is okay to ask if that's you admit it is.

Comment: yes. it is not homework excerise sir, it is a question send to me by my friend and he has blackened out. but i have tried my best ans have told as far as i could do.

Comment: This is a special case of [Liouville's theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Liouville%27s_Theorem_(Number_Theory)).

Comment: @Greg Martin could  you elaborate please.